# incremental build - to re-build .o file only when .c or .h file is changed using .d dependency file

Tags: makefile, compilation, gnu-make, incremental-build

My makefile is currently working fine as it is creating .o files for all .c files in different directories and creating executable file. If I do changes in any .c file, then after building it just compiles only those changed .c files. Its fine. But, if I do changes in any .h file, then all dependent .c files should be rebuild. But, it is not doing that as dependency file is generated but not mapped to it. So, please help me to do that.

I have dependency (.d) files in output directory. I want it to map to target in main makefile so that by changes in any .h file, the dependent .c file will be recopiled.[This is some part of my code...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qknet.png)

this is my .c to .o conversion code:

```
%.$(OBJ_FILE_SUFFIX) : %.$(C_FILE_SUFFIX)
    @echo ********************************************************
    @echo Compiling $< ...
    @echo Generating $(OBJECT_OUTPUT_PATH)/$@ ...
    @$(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(C_DEF_PARAM) @$(INCLUDE_PATHS_FILE) $< -o $(OBJECT_OUTPUT_PATH)/$@
    @echo Done ...
```

It is working fine if any changes done in .c file, only that file is getting re-compiled, but not happening same with .h file.
Thank you.

Comment: Did you remember to `-include output/*.d`?

Comment: Yes. I did that.

Comment: I have generated .d files, I have included them and now what to do further?

Comment: You generate dependency files, you include them but it does not work as you expect. So, there is probably a bug in your Makefile. As you do not show your Makefile we cannot help. Please design a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), show it **completely**, explain what command you run, what result you get and what other result you expected.

Comment: There is no bug in the Makefile. It is working fine for building.

Comment: It is also re-compiling the .c file if change done in .c file. I want to add do changes in it so that it will re-compile the .c files for changes done in .h file. and only those .c files have to be re-compiled which includes that .h file.

Comment: I have attached one picture of my makefile. Please have a look towards it.

Comment: @Rishab_katariya If there is no bug in your Makefile with what part of your project do you need help? Note: please do not post pictures of your code, they cannot be copy-pasted. Put your code directly in your question and format it correctly. And try to be as complete as you can: the part of Makefile you show is not self-sufficient (it does not show how you generate the dependency files, most make variables are not defined...).

Comment: @Rishab_katariya:  Visit, maybe, the [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) sections of the help center?

Comment: Hello @RenaudPacalet , Good Morning. I can understand your point but makefile is distributed in many folders and can't post all of them. Just guide me with general steps to use .d file to rebuild .o files if any change done in .c or .h file.

Comment: http://make.mad-scientist.net/papers/advanced-auto-dependency-generation/